# How to serialize a JSON object in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not able to serialize the JSON object "data", shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myObj = {'first_name':{'answers':{'0':'John'}}};
var postdata = {'data':myObj};
$.post("get_note.php", postdata, function(data){
    $('#note').text(data);
});

</script>
```

Following is the code in file get_note.php:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST['data']);
?>
```

This results in the following being printed to the #note element.

```
Array ( [first_name] => )
```

The array appears to be empty.  I was expecting a multidimensional array in the PHP file.  Why is it empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client, you can serialize by doing `JSON.stringify()` for pure javascript. On the server, you'll need to do a php `json_decode()` on the string.

So on the client:

```
var postdata = {'data':JSON.stringify(myObj)};
```

and on the server:

```
$myObj = json_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['data']),true);
```

References:

js JSON.stringify(): http://www.json.org/js.html

php json_decode(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Older browsers, such as IE7 and IE8, don't implement `JSON.stringify`. You might take a look at [Crockford's JSON-implementation in Javascript](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) in this case.

Comment: Yes, that's the best place to get it: json.org. Use it instead of the native implementation.

Comment: Note that in order to get json_decode to work correctly, I needed to use $data = json_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['data']), true);

Comment: @Civil777, I'll add that to the post. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You could try sending a serialized JSON array and decrypt it in server side.

To serialize JSON array use this:

```
var my_json_array = { index: 11 };
JSON.stringify(my_json_array);
```

Then in server side you can convert (decode) it to PHP array like this:

```
$json = $_POST["my_json_array"];
$my_array = json_decode($json);
```

So your code would turn in this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var data = {'first_name':{'answers':{'0':'John'}}};
var postdata = {'data':JSON.stringify(data)};
$.post("get_note.php", postdata, function(data){
    $('#note').text(data);
});

</script>
```

and

```
<?php

print_r(json_decode($_POST['data']));
?>
```

---

How it was said, this solution is good for new browsers (with native JSON support) for older ones this solution won`t work.

More about JSON support in browsers you can read here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Native_encoding_and_decoding_in_browsers

Comment: Like how you just copied the answer above.

Comment: @Civil777, it's cool. It's a slightly different take with more code. And we all borrow from each other here to get a rounded answer. "There is nothing new under the sun" (Ecclesiastes 1:9). :)

Comment: Well It wasn`t like i copied it. When I started writing this I didnt saw other solution(It happened simultaneously). And its just natural that knowing people think the same.